# Unexpected DropdownButtonFormField behaviour

Tags: flutter, dart

After updating Flutter to 1.17.0 I noticed `DropdownButtonFormField` behaving unexpectedly.

When I'm selecting an item that I've disallowed to select, it still gets updated in the `DropdownButtonFormField`.

I created [gist in dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/fcc40521b341b7dd22d43882388e1c4c) reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the [source code of DropdownButtonFormField](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart#L1444), I saw that the `value` property gets passed into the super constructor from `FormField` where it is used as `initialValue`. (around line 1444)
This is quite confusing, actually.

`FormField`s manage their own state. A work around for this is by giving it a key, and ask it to reset its state once you changed the value, so uses the initial value again:

```
final key = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return DropdownButtonFormField(
    key: key,
    value: _value,
    onChanged: (newValue) {
        // Allows only to select second value
        if (newValue == 'second') {
          setState(() => _value = newValue);
        } else {
          print('Cannot set other values than second');
          // Explicidly sets value as second <- this gets ignored
          setState(() {
            _value = 'second';
            key.currentState.reset();
          });
        }
      },
      ...
```

But I see somebody just added [a pull request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/57037) to change this